# Code compare tools don't line up on dual monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, alignment

I have setup Visual Studio to use an external code compare tool.

I've tried both Beyond Compare and DiffMerge and when the window is expanded to cover both monitors they don't align.

Can someone show me how to line them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual display was offset:

[image]

Fixing the display resolves the problem:

[image]